# How to go away from aws android authentication activity to another activity?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

sorry for this question, the thing is that I am presenting trouble to pass from the authentication activity that provide aws on android to the main activity. If something is uncorrect it will appear some messagge, but if everything is correct the  app don't do anything :( Thanks!

This is de documentation [AWS - Add User Sign-in to Your Mobile App with Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html)

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.ui.AuthUIConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.ui.SignInUI;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSStartupHandler;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSStartupResult;

public class AuthenticatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authenticator);

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(final AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {
                AuthUIConfiguration config =
                        new AuthUIConfiguration.Builder()
                                .userPools(true)  // true? show the Email and Password UI
                                .logoResId(R.mipmap.ic_solvo) // Change the logo
                                .backgroundColor(Color.WHITE) // Change the backgroundColor
                                .isBackgroundColorFullScreen(true) // Full screen backgroundColor the backgroundColor full screenff
                                .fontFamily("sans-serif-light") // Apply sans-serif-light as the global font
                                .canCancel(true)
                                .build();
                SignInUI signinUI = (SignInUI) AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getClient(AuthenticatorActivity.this, SignInUI.class);
                signinUI.login(AuthenticatorActivity.this, MenuActivity.class).authUIConfiguration(config).execute();
            }
        }).execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Activity you want to go from this?

Comment: From AuthenticatorActivity to MenuActivity

Comment: Why dont you just put `startActivity(new Intent(AuthenticatorActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));` somewhere when the activity complete!

Comment: Because I don't know when the user is login successfully :(

Comment: Try that in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside onComplete at the Bottom:

```
if(awsStartupResult.isIdentityIdAvailable()){
    startActivity(new Intent(AuthenticatorActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: Nope the app do nothing when i click the sign-in button :(

Comment: Are you all set in client code like is your Activity registered in manifest? According to the documentation everything should work!

Comment: yeap, look ->
        <activity android:name=".AuthenticatorActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MenuActivity"></activity>